# how to check text color in watir for drop down boxes attributes

Tags: ruby, automation, watir

```
contents = $ie.select_list(:id, "dropdown").getAllContents
puts contents.currentstyle.color
```

It showing error as

```
1) Error:
test_01(TC_Login):
NoMethodError: undefined method `currentstyle' for
```

Can any one help as i need to fetch particular record with particular color

Comment: It would be better to see the html and css. Maybe the style is not set for the dropdown contents, but the dropdown itself. Anyway, this is light on information for people to help you well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have HTML like this:

```
<select name="list" id="select_list">
  <option value="1" style="color:blue" SELECTED>Name1</option>
  <option value="2" style="color:green">Name2</option>
  <option value="3" style="color:green">Name3</option>
</select>
```

The only way I have found to get the colour of an option was to access it directly (from the win32ole object). The following would output the colour of the first option.

```
puts $ie.select_list(:id, "dropdown").document.options(0).style.color
```

If you want to get the Watir::Option object that has the matching colour, you can do:

```
matching_colour = 'green'   # Colour you want

# Iterate through the options to find the first match
select_list_element = ie.select_list(:id, 'dropdown')
matching_option = nil
select_list_element.document.options.each{ |o|
  if o.style.color == matching_colour
    matching_option = select_list_element.option(:text, o.text)
    break
  end
}

# Do something with the option if one was found
if match_option.nil?
  #Nothing matches
else
  #Do something with the option, like select it
  matching_option.select
end
```